# Data in array collection shows empty when retrieving info

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, arraycollection

I'm creating a web app with symfony. I'm currently building the forms and as I've never used the ManyToMany relation I'm having some problem with retrieving the information.

The form I'm working with is this one:

[image]

The point is that when I'm retrieving the information of the array in the twig template, the data property inside the array shows empty, when there is Alumne's entities created. Let me show you.

Twig template (create page):

[image]

As you can see, what I pretend is to retrieve the info of every Alumne entity inside the array.

What I get doing this is:

[image]

The alumnes field is completly empty. But if I change the form Builder to this:

[image]

(I have also changed a little bit the twig template to make it more readable)
It works!

[image]

And as you can see there is an Alumne created.

The point is, as you can see, the select and option tag it creates is kinda ugly, I want to custom so it can fit the rest of the forms. So that's why I need a CollectionType in the builder and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Also if I check the dump(form.alumnes.vars.data) it shows empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is, that you use the `CollectionType` instead of the `EntityType`. To load data from the Database into a form, you should use the `EntityType` https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

If you leave the type out, Symfony will try to guess what form element to use and will (correctly) guess the `EntityType`